# How to center CardHeader title in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I place title center on CardHeader (Material-UI)?

I am using Material-UI v0.18.7

Here is my code. I tried with textAlign: 'center' to titleStyle prop but that doesn't work.

```
const myTheme = {
   cardHeaderStylePref:{
      background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #430089, #82ffa1)',
      color: config.actualWhite,
      height: 30,
      padding: 0
    }
}
<Card>
     <CardHeader
            title={this.props.prefName}
            style={myTheme.cardHeaderStylePref}
            subtitleColor={myTheme.color}
            titleColor={myTheme.color}
            titleStyle={{textAlign: 'center'}}
      >
      </CardHeader>
      <CardText>
            Sample text
      </CardText>
  </Card>
```

Comment: try giving `display: block` to the element's parent.

Comment: You mean to Card?

Comment: yeah, Card. and check if `CardHeader` has any float applied to it. if it's floated, remove or overwrite the float.As I can't see the styles being applied to the both of the elements it's hard to determine exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use css style textAlign to move title center

```
style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks

Comment: What if i have an avatar in my header? How do i align it in center?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing inline styling, passing a class name should be a good option.

```
<CardHeader title="Subscribe" className={classes.heading} />
```

Comment: StackOverflow frowns on code-only answers. It slows people down, who are looking at a lot of potential answers because they have to stop and reverse-engineer pure-code answers to figure out what the fix is or what the code is trying to do. Please edit the answer with a brief explanation (I found this on the low-quality posts review queue but giving you a chance to fix it before your answer gets deleted).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question unless you know the content of the heading class

Answer (score 0):

In the component:

```
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    heading: {
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
  })
)

const MyComponent = () => {
 
 const classes = useStyles()

 return <CardHeader title="Subscribe" className={classes.heading} />
}
```

This works with `"@material-ui/core` `v4.11.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is very simple once you understand the component hierarchy - so inside the `CardHeader` component is the title's `Typography` component which you can pass `props` to via the `CardHeader` component's `titleTypographyProps` prop like so:

```
<CardHeader
  title="Title"
  titleTypographyProps={{ textAlign: "center" }}
/>
```

The same applies for the `CardHeader` component's  `subheading` prop where the `subheadingTypographyProps` can be passed like so:

```
<CardHeader
  title="Title"
  titleTypographyProps={{ textAlign: "center" }}
  subheader="Subheading"
  subheaderTypographyProps={{ textAlign: "center" }}
/>
```